# In this passage, what does "it" and "one" refer to and what does "blows up" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Two questions:

1. What does **it** and **one** refer to in the following sentences?
   I myself think that it refers to the **very fabric of spacetime**. Am I correct?
2. What is the meaning of the verb ***blows up*** in this context?

> According to quantum
>   theory, the very fabric of spacetime is subject to the
>   violent fluctuations caused by the formation of virtual particles
>   on the small scale—fluctuations that become ever
>   more extreme the smaller the scale until eventually **it** all
>   blows up when **one** theoretically gets down to a point

Comment: "One" here refers to the observer.

Comment: The referent for the "it" seems to be "spacetime."

Answer (score 1):

My reading of that is that *it* is *quantum theory* and the theory *blows up* in the sense that it breaks down at very small scale and runs to infinity when the scale reaches zero (a point).

Comment: *Point* here might be metaphorical - like [*up to a point*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/up_to_a_point).

Answer (score 0):

My sense is that the 'it' is connected to the 'all' to make an expression 'it all' - which refers to the whole bunch or particles, that are undergergoing their process, which is being described.

You could say that 'it all' - all those particles in their process' is equivalent to 'the very fabric of spacetime' but in this case I think it is more accurate to think of 'all those particles boiling around'.

The 'one' is 'one particle' I think - which has reached a point of - something - that then causes the whole thing (ie all the other relative particles) to 'blow up'.

'Blows up' means 'explode' here, I feel.